# Adding multiple ranges into one argument

Tags: vba

Good day folks, I have this bit of code which works just fine:

```
   If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("D6:D15")) Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "busses"
    Else
    MsgBox "Select Only Cells With Asset ID", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
    End If
```

What I would like to do is to add more ranges into that line, like so:

```
       If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("D6:D15") Or ("G6:G15") Or ("J6:J15")) Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "busses"
    Else
    MsgBox "Select Only Cells With Asset ID", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

But it won't work, any ideas appriciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `UNION` may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a range composed of different cells:

```
If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("D6:D15,G6:G15,J6:J15")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "busses"
Else
    MsgBox "Select Only Cells With Asset ID", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```